# Will GNU GCC keep track of objects which have previously been dereferenced using the arrow operator?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, dereference

Using the following struct,

```
struct A
{
    A(int d1, int d2)
    {
        data1 = d1;
        data2 = d2;
    }

    int data1, data2;
};
```

will the last line in the function below dereference the pointer again, or will the compiler know to use the previously dereferenced object?

```
int main()
{
    A* a = new A(1, 2);

    //dereference a
    cout << a->data1 << endl;

    //dereference a again?
    cout << a->data2 << endl;
}
```

If not, are there any compilers that might do this?

I know that I can perform an experiment to test my question however I do not know assembly language very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that in cases like this the generated code will not literally perform another dereference. This will occur when the compiler can tell for sure that `a` won't change between the two statements.

This is a common category of optimisation, and is the cause of many bugs when people violate *strict aliasing* rules (because this potentially breaks the compiler's ability to detect that `a` hasn't changed).

Comment: But should we even discuss dereferencing here? In this situation there is only a numeric value (pointer) and two well known offsets to it.

Comment: @Logman Are you saying that the first use of the arrow pointer doesn't need to dereference the pointer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is no need to dereferencing pointer `a`. Program just access value of pointer there and not `*a` itself. Then it takes this value and add static offset for `data1` and `data2` to calculate memory addresses for them. Optimization will just cache value of pointer 'a' to not preform RAM accessing twice but anyway probably there will be no `a` value in RAM anyway. This is just a theory and need to be validate by checking actually assembly but I just want to point out that "dereferencing" cost in this example is non-existent.

Comment: @Logman: What you just described is exactly what a dereference is: reading the value of one thing (the pointer) to determine the location of another (the `A` and, by extension, its `int` members). In this particular example, the compiler can elide the allocation, the `A`, the dereference, all of it.

Comment: Yep, but it this theoretical dereferencing meaning (accessing object by it's reference) the answer to OP question is no. You need always dereference object to access it as it is the meaning of dereferencing. But from my point of view OP thinks that program must do some extra costly operations to access object data and this is completely false. There probably will be no extra operation but just grabbing memory from an address.

Comment: @Logman Dereferencing was never more than that. You're rejecting a claim that nobody made. The question is about whether dereferencing must always occur twice when `->` is uttered twice, and the answer is no.

Comment: Then why you answer is yes?

Comment: @Logman Because the question was phrased in the opposite way around? Not sure whether you're being deliberately obtuse at this point...